# Why is my DIV changing my cursor?

Tags: css, html

I have two DIV's and when I put DIV #2 inside of DIV#1 and then view my page, when I put my cursor over DIV #2 it changes the cursor to the select (highlight) cursor?

I am very confused?

Comment: some HTML/CSS snippets would help give us an idea of what you're trying to do

Comment: As NoCarrier said, its pretty much impossible for people to make a guess as to what the issue is without some example code to see. Try and find the absolute minimum case of html/css that you need to reproduce the error & post it. Also tell us what browser you're seeing the problem in.

Comment: boggles my mind someone would vote this up. About as unhelpful of a question as it gets. Help us help you!

Answer (score 2):

You must have something in the div that the browser is interpreting as text.

Comment: its interpreting the DIV as text, lol. When I take it out it's fine. That's bs...

Answer (score 2):

Is the CSS property for cursor set? It may have the value 'text' set for it's property value.

Look for

```
div {
    cursor: text;
}
```

Comment: I think its just "cursor: text"

Answer (score 1):

Rules other than "cursor" can change the cursor also. I think using 'zoom' can change the cursor to a highlight/text cursor under certain circumstances for example.

Comment: Do you know what these circumstances are?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a big problem you can always change the cursor manually in css

```
cursor: pointer;
```

CSS Cursor Reference: http://cndbooks.com/csscursors.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is the just the type of thing [FireFox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html) w/ [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) can instantly help you figure out... Just right-click and 'Inspect Element' and CSS is given. Voila.